# Preloading participant instances and issuing corresponding identities

Tags: hyperledger-composer

What is a best practice or pattern that could be followed around the initial creation of participant instances and issuing corresponding identities for a deployed business network?  Is the expectation there will be some sort of bootstrapped config or transaction that will preload participants...or will that be the responsibility of an admin / regulator to do this AFTER the network is deployed...or something all together different???  The docs talk about an existing participant (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/participantsandidentities.html) but how did that existing participant get loaded into the network?

Answer (score 1):

We are tracking this requirement using this issue:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/670